# Java illegal start of expression

Tags: java, expression

I have done a google around but can't get my head around what's wrong with my code here.

I'm getting an **Illegal start of expression** error in the if statement at the first 'Else if'

I'm pretty new to Java but trying to quickly learn as its a requirement of my computing course I'm hoping to do.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class net_salary{

public static void main(String[]args){    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    

    int income;
    int incometax;
    int afterincometax;
    int nationalinsurance;
    int afterni;
    int pension;

    income = in.nextInt();       

    if(income = 0) {
        incometax = 0;
    } else if (income >=9000 & <=21000) {
        incometax = income * 0.15;
    } else if (income >=21000 & <=31000) {
        incometax = income * 0.2;       
    } else if (income >=31000 & <=50000) {
        incometax = income * 0.225
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)` instead of `else if (income >=9000 & <=21000)`.

Similarly for the other `else if` expressions.

You have to make two separate comparisons to income. You can't say "if income is greater than or equal to 9000 or less than or equal to 21000". You must say "if income is greater than 9000 or income is less than or equal to 21000".

`&` is a bitwise AND. `&&` is logical AND.

As stated by others, `income = 0` should read `income == 0`.

Comment: Hi!, Thanks for the reply even with the double && I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Help a idiot out and show me how it would look? I'm getting what your saying but not sure how to put it down - Cheers again.

Comment: `else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)`, as above. You must repeat `income` in the second comparison.

Comment: Yep indeed - Thanks a lot for that it suddenly clicked in my head. Cheers a lot for your help sir!

Comment: "& is a bitwise AND. && is logical AND". Actually in this case `&` is also a logical operator.

Comment: This is true, but because `&&` is the conventional logical operator, I wanted it to be clear to the original poster that there are (usually) distinct uses for these operators. +1 for you.

Comment: In fact, I disagree with allowing `&` to be used as a logical operator, as it can make reading over source code confusing, especially to new programmers.

Answer (score 3):

You need && not &, and repeat the variable 'income' :

```
else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)
```

You are also using = where you probably mean ==

```
if(income == 0)
```

= assigns a value, == tests whether two values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Your if/else if block expression always should results as boolean (either true/false). In Java, && represents AND, & is bitwise operator which manipulates bits.

```
if(income == 0)
    {
        incometax = 0;

    }
**else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)**
    {
        incometax = income * 0.15;
    }

else if (income >=21000 && income <=31000)
    {
        incometax = income * 0.2;

    }

else if (income >=31000 && income <=50000)
    {
        incometax = income * 0.225
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(income = 0)`

should be

`if(income == 0)`

and

`else if (income >=9000 & <=21000)`

(and it's followers) should be

`else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)`

and looks like you you need to make some of your variables double instead of int.

Comment: Your comment regarding the `else if` block seems kind of bizarre. You're still using bitwise `AND` in your corrected version and you're checking if `9000 <= 21000` (why would you do ever do that?).

Comment: ... I think you meant to check if `income <= 21000`. :-\.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Please see this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2. `&` can be a bitwise or logical operator depending upon the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Check the usage of "=", "==", "&", "&&" operators in Java.

```
public class net_salary{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    int income, ncometax, afterincometax, nationalinsurance, afterni, pension; 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   
    income = in.nextInt();

    if(income == 0) {
       incometax = 0;
    } else if (income >= 9000 && income <= 21000) {
       incometax = income * 0.15;
    } else if (income >=21000 && income <= 31000) {
       incometax = income * 0.2;
    } else if (income >=31000 && income <= 50000) {
    }
  }
}
```